# Divide Datadog metric by the x-axis scale

Tags: time, statistics, time-series, metrics, datadog

I have a timeseries graph where we are looking at a metric against a limit.
However, depending on the scale of the x-axis, the averaging of the values can make the metric look widely different:

[image: per day]
Here the x-axis ticks in 5 minute intervals

[image: per week]
Same graph with x-axis ticks of 1 hour

Since the limit is per second, can I divide the value of the metric by the number of seconds per x-axis tick?

So for the first graph it would be `a/300` and the second graph it would be `a/3600`